# indexPathForSelectedRow returns nil although I have a cell programmatically selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` which I load with some application settings. I need the table to be single-select, and since the table holds settings there might be a chance some cell will be programmatically selected based on the setting enabled status.

Currently, I'm experiencing a weird behaviour where if I programmatically select a cell then `indexPathForSelectedRow` returns `nil` (when it should return the index for the cell I selected), thus when I tap on a second cell (to change the currenty selected setting) I end up with two cells selected (even when I set `allowMultipleSelection` to false in my tableView object).

Here's my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell")

    if let cell = cell {
        // tableObject is an array containing settings model
        let row = tableObject[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = row.settingValue
        if row.selected {
            cell.setSelected(true, animated: false)
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        }
        cell.tag = row.id
    }

    return cell!
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
    // oldIndex is always nil for the cell I called setSelected in cellForRowAtIndexPath
    if let oldIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        if let oldCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(oldIndex) {
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(oldIndex, animated: true)
            oldCell.accessoryType = .None           
        }
    }

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        cell.setSelected(true, animated: true)
        cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    }

    return indexPath
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        cell.accessoryType = .None
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }
    return indexPath
}
```

Any idea how I can always have only one cell selected at a time?

Thanks!

Comment: you need to use DIDSELECT not WILL SELECT and in method you already have indexpath why you are do code like tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

Comment: @NitinGohel With the above code even when I change it to use didSelectRow I still observe the same behaviour

Comment: let me post an answer give me few mint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case someone else comes across this same behaviour, it seems that selecting the cell through `cell.setSelected()` it's not the same as invoking `tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath()` method. Selecting the row with the latest does the job perfectly and solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Note that calling `tableView.reloadData()` resets the `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` to nil.

here how you can accomplish table view single selection through `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` :

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.accessoryType = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow == indexPath ? .checkmark : .none
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        if let visiblePaths = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows
        {
            for visibleIndexPath in visiblePaths
            {
                let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: visibleIndexPath)
                if visibleIndexPath == indexPath
                {
                    cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
                }
                else
                {
                    cell?.accessoryType = .none
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, the `tableView.reloadData()` does reset the `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow`! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create an array like

```
var arrSelectCell = [NSIndexPath]()
```

And do the code at `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` like following:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if arrSelectCell.contains(indexPath) {
        if let oldCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {

                if let index = arrSelectCell.indexOf(indexPath) {
                    arrSelectCell.removeAtIndex(index)
                }
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
            oldCell.accessoryType = .None
        }

    }
    else
    {
        arrSelectCell.append(indexPath)
        if let selectCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
            selectCell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        }


    }
```

and also dont forget to set a code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to check already checked and unchecked cell maintain after reuse cell also. So need to few code you need to write as following.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("serchCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SearchTableViewCell

            if arrSelectCell.contains(indexPath)
            {
                    cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
            }
            else
            {
                    cell.accessoryType = .None
            }

            return cell
        }
```

Comment: This code doesn't work because `ArrSelectedCell` is never been initialized. And why is it optional and starts with a capital letter?

Comment: there is no any restriction with capital and this is not a objective c so that dont need to initialized. let me show you screenshot as well

Comment: This somehow feels like a hack to me. ```indexPathForSelectedRow``` should return a ```NSIndexPath``` object regardless if I set my cell as selected using ```setSelected``` or if it was the user who tapped into it and selected it.

Comment: lol, you **do** need to initialize the array in Swift otherwise is keeps being `nil`. It's a naming convention to start variable names with a lowercase letter, it makes the code easier to read. (See the syntax highlighter).

Comment: It cannot work because all optional chained lines for example `ArrSelectedCell?.append(indexPath)` are not executed if `ArrSelectedCell` is `nil`.

Comment: i just change my code and now its working good thanks for correct me :)